# What is /w 1 and /C in PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, parameters, command-line-interface

I've seen PowerShell commands that start `powershell /w 1 /C ...some command here...`. What are the `/w` and `/C` arguments? Is there some documentation for this? Googling it didn't return anything that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) documents the Windows PowerShell CLI (the command-line parameters supported).

<sup>The PowerShell *Core* equivalent is [about_pwsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), reflecting the different executable name, `pwsh`. The rest of this answer applies analogously PowerShell Core as well, though not all parameters are supported on all platforms, notably not `-WindowStyle` on Unix.</sup>

You can get the same information by running `powershell.exe -?`

Note that while `powershell.exe` *also* supports `/` as the parameter-name sigil, it is more typical to use `-`, which is the character used exclusively *inside* a PowerShell session; therefore, the explanation below uses `-c` instead of `/c` and `-w` instead of `/w`.

As inside a PowerShell session, you can use *elastic syntax*, i.e., it is sufficient to use a parameter name's *unambiguous prefix*, though in your particular case the command actually uses explicitly defined short *alias names*:<sup>[1]</sup>

- `-w` is short for `-WindowStyle`

  - `-WindowStyle` accepts *symbolic* values, and for readability it's better to use them instead of the numeric equivalents:

    - `Normal` (`0`)
    - `Maximized` (`3`)
    - `Minimized` (`2`)
    - `Hidden` (`1`)
- `-c` is short for `-Command`

---

<sup>[1] These explicitly defined aliases aren't documented for Windows PowerShell (they now are for PowerShell Core), but you can see them [in the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/609d610c710e637c300927f214115fd5e7d215d0/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/CommandLineParameterParser.cs#L724). Note that if `-c` weren't defined as an alias, it would be ambiguous, because both `-Command` and `-ConfigurationName` start with `c`.</sup>